# node.js claims/roles access control module

Tags: node.js, security, sails.js

I'm building a new node.js/Sails application. Authentication is easy. I'm using a third party OAuth2 provider (Microsoft Azure, don't ask!) and passport.js.

I need to now implement resource authorisation. I don't want to use anything specific to my OAuth2 provider (Azure Graph API) incase I want to support other providers in the future.

I would like to implement a claims based authentication system but I'm not wedded to claims.

What is the best approach to authorisation in a large express/sails app? I need it to be fully dynamic and granular.

I have found [node-acl](https://www.npmjs.org/package/acl) which looks good but there doesn't seem to be much else to compare and contrast.